# Kawamata BPF applied to a semi-positive line bundle using Demailly's holomorphic Morse inequalities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, complex-manifolds

Let $M$ be a compact complex manifold equipped with a line bundle $L$ which has curvature which is non-negative and strictly positive outside of a measure zero set $Z$. In his paper  ["Holomorphic Morse inequalities"](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/morse.pdf) Demailly proved that $M$ is Moishezon (this was a new proof of the Grauert-Riemenschneider conjecture, originally due to Siu).

I want to show that if $M$ is projective, $L$ is semi-ample, that is, base point free. I have a very simple argument, which I guess should be known, but I was unable to find it.

The proof is based on Kawamata BPF theorem, and Demailly's holomorphic Morse inequalities.

Kawamata BPF:
Let $L$ be a nef line bundle on a projective manifold $M$ such that $L^{\otimes a}\otimes K_M^{-1}$ is big and nef for some $a$. Then there exists some $m$ such that $mL$ is base point free.

*Here I was wrong, and I need to apply a correction, thanks to
the user YangMills. The bundle $L^{\otimes a}\otimes K_M^{-1}$
should be big **and** nef. Then the argument I gave becomes invalid, unless $Z$ is very special.*

Demailly:
$$
h^1(E^k) - h^0(E^k) \leq -\frac{k^n}{n!} \int_U
\left(\frac{\sqrt 1}{2\pi} \Theta_E\right)^n + o(k^n),
$$
where $E$ is a line bundle, $\Theta_E$ its curvature, and $U\subset M$ the set where $\Theta_E$ has at least $n-1$ positive eigenvalues.

Semipositive line bundles are clearly nef.
To apply Kawamata to the semipositive line bundle $L$, we need only to check that $L^{\otimes a}\otimes K_M^{-1}$ is big. However, for very big $a$ the curvature of $L^{\otimes a}\otimes K_M^{-1}$ is strictly positive outside of a small neighbourhood of the zero set $Z$, which contributes very little to the integral $ \int_U (\frac{\sqrt 1}{2\pi} \Theta_E)^n$, hence this integral is positive, and $E=L^{\otimes a}\otimes K_M^{-1}$ is big, because $h^0(E^k)$ grows as $k^n$.

I would be very grateful to anyone who can give me the reference to this, or point out where I did an error (or give a counterexample).

Reference:
Kawamata, Y., Pluricanonical systems on minimal algebraic varieties,
Invent. Math., 79, (1985), no. 3, 567-588.

J.-P. Demailly,
Holomorphic Morse inequalities,
Several complex variables and complex geometry,
Part 2 (Santa Cruz, CA, 1989), 93--114,
Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., 52, Part 2,
Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1991.

Comment: Error: in Kawamata's BPF theorem you need to assume that $L^a\otimes K_M^{-1}$ is nef and big. Possible counterexample: Mumford's example (Ex. 4.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.6402) has a nef and big line bundle which is not bpf, and yet it admits a smooth Hermitian metric with semipositive curvature. I think if you check the proof in that paper it should be true that the curvature is strictly positive away from a measure zero set.

Comment: many thanks! I would try to correct the question

Comment: small correction to my comment: what I meant to write is that in Mumford's example the line bundle is not semiample (not just bpf)

Comment: @Invariance Which theorem do you mean? I believe it is about 6.1 in Kawamata's paper, no?